# Is there a tutorial that teaches common Ruby programming idioms used by experienced programmers, but may not be obvious to newcomers?

Tags: ruby, idioms

I'm looking for a Ruby's equivalent of [Code Like a Pythonista: Idiomatic Python](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html)

Desirable features:

- easy to read
- single document which covers all topics: tips, tricks, guidelines, caveats, and pitfalls
- size less than a book
- idioms should work out of the box for the standard distribution (`% sudo apt-get install ruby irb rdoc`)

Please, put one tutorial per answer if possible, with an example code from the tutorial and its meaning.

UPDATE:

These are the most closest to the above description resources I've encountered:

- [Ruby Idioms](http://blog.angelbob.com/posts/244)
- [Ruby User's Guide](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/index.html)

Comment: poignantguide.net - but even that won't measure up to your standards for instant-learning I think.

Comment: @Gishu: the direction is right, but I'd prefer something terser.

Comment: Please correct the link to the "Ruby Idioms" page: http://blog.angelbob.com/posts/244

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Ruby Idioms (originally from RubyGarden)](http://blog.angelbob.com/posts/244) is my usual reference for idioms.  It's clearly organized and fairly complete.  As the author says, these are from RubyGarden, which [used to be](http://web.archive.org/web/20071016094753/www.rubygarden.org/Ruby/page/show/HomePage) really cool (thanks [Wayback Machine](http://www.archive.org/)).  But now seems to be [offline](http://rubygarden.org/).

Answer (score 9):

Here's a slideshow:  [Idiomatic Ruby](http://cbcg.net/talks/rubyidioms/).

Excerpt:

'`until`' works like '`while not`'

```
  x = x * 2 until x > 100
```

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest the perennial classic: **[Why's Poignant guide](http://poignantguide.net/ruby/)**

It's both an introduction to Ruby and an investigation into the Ruby Way.

Comment: I would too, +1.  Unfortunately, the OP ruled it out in the comments to the question.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [The Ruby Way](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328844) and [The Rails Way](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321445619), they aren't tutorials but I think they will cover what you're looking for.

Comment: "The Ruby Way" is worth reading.

Answer (score 3):

While not directly a tutorial, here is a blog that you'll find on topic

http://its.arubything.com/

Answer (score 3):

How about [Mr. Neigborly's Humble Little Ruby Book](http://www.humblelittlerubybook.com/book/)

Excerpt:

```
IO.foreach("textfile.txt") {|line| puts line }
```

Comment: The level of the book is a complete beginner at programming.

Answer (score 1):

An executable guide to understanding Ruby's closures, [closures-in-ruby.rb](http://innig.net/software/ruby/closures-in-ruby.rb).

Answer (score 1):

I found this blog recently. Haven't really got into it yet and the couple of posts I have read were a bit beginner focussed.
YMMV

http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/